# Асинхронное декодирование SVG-иконки для элемента списка

Tags: java, svg, batik

Есть архив, в котором находятся около двух тысяч svg-файлов. Моя задача - создать список формата `[Иконка] Имя svg в архиве`. Для работы с svg я использую библиотеку Batik от Apache. При декодировании лишь одной иконки в основном потоке интерфейс заметно подвисает (да и вообще работа с файлами в основном потоке - плохая практика), поэтому я решил производить декодирование асинхронно, но после выполнения кода иконка в списке не появляется. Пожалуйста, подскажите, где я ошибся и что нужно исправить, чтобы иконка появилась? Код содержит костыли (результат перехода с Java для Android на Java для ПК), но, тем не менее, я старался хорошо его откомментировать. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Всё начинается здесь, в **UserInterface.class**, где происходит наполнение списка:

```
// Обновляет список иконок.
private void reloadIcons() {
    // ...

    // Обновление списка иконок в репозитории.
    DefaultListModel<String> mGetNewIconsListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    try {
        // Получение списка файлов в архиве.
        ZipFile mRepository = new ZipFile(new File(Constants.FILE_DATABASE));
        Main.mRepositoryIcons = Utilities.getRepositoryIcons(mRepository);
        for (String mSvg : Main.mRepositoryIcons)
            mGetNewIconsListModel.addElement(mSvg);
    } catch (IOException mException) {
        mException.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Установка отрисовщика элементов списка.
    mGetNewIconsList.setCellRenderer(new GetNewIconsListRenderer());
    // Установка значений в список.
    mGetNewIconsList.setModel(mGetNewIconsListModel);
}
```

Отрисовщик элементов списка **GetNewIconsListRenderer.class**: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NiwJDtpW)

Асинхронный загрузчик **SvgDecoder.class**: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y8wZbyax)